# How to create EXPLAIN_PLAN table on Amazon RDS database?

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds

How to create EXPLAIN_PLAN table having no access to console? Is there an option to tick somewhere?

Comment: are you able to connect to your rds from local computer?

Comment: yes, using python+cx_Oracle and sqlplus

Comment: Have you tried `set autotrace traceonly`?

Comment: I don't think it works outside sql*plus

Comment: But you told me that you could connect to your database through the SQL*Plus tool. Next time express yourself clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are referring to **PLAN_TABLE** used in "explain plan" commands. In Oracle 11.2 it's already created by default as a temporary table in the SYS schema (PLAN_TABLE$) with public synonym and privileges to all users.

So "explain plan" should work right out of the box and then you can read the results from the table:

```
explain plan for select * from dual;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 272002086

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It's a temporary table, so the contents aren't saved between sessions. If for any reason you think you still need a plan table, I think you can create one exactly like the original in your account by using the result of this query:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','PLAN_TABLE$', 'SYS') from dual;
```

You'll need to modify the name and owner (remove "SYS." and the "$") and maybe make it a permanent table if that's what you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sounds like a good idea, but executing "select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);" via cx_Oracle cursor gives me a "Error: cannot fetch last explain plan from PLAN_TABLE", but it works through sqlplus